# Customize SuiteCommerce Checkout Page

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

Clicking checkout button it redirect to here.
https://checkout.netsuite.com/s.nl/c.578860/sc.4/.f?ext=F

But where could I find this page template?

what c.578860 mean and sc.4 means?

Comment: Some people said you could find it in SSP Application in File Cabinet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c.578860` denotes your company Id 
`c` stands for company and `578860` is your organization Id

`sc.4` denotes site category Id
`sc` stands for site category and `4` denotes site category Id

When you select an item and add to cart the sitecategory id will be appended to the checkout URL along with your organization id.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can I find that category then?

Comment: If I want to edit that page then where could I get that template file?

Answer (score 0):

You can find checkout template at

Web Site Hosting Files > Live Hosting Files > SSP Applications > NetSuite Inc. - Checkout X.YY.Z > Reference Checkout > templates

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite generated pages can be edited in the Theme section (Setup > SiteBuilder > Themes using the tags). All other NetSuite generated pages such as checkout/cart/myaccount pages are generated by the ssp files in the (Web Site Hosting Files > Live Hosting Files > SSP Applications > NetSuite Inc. XXXX > Development) Folder. (checkout.ssp, my_account.ssp and cart.ssp)